# Posição das tabelas

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

olá, eu gostaria de saber como posso numerar a tabela por numeros,
exemplo, cada  teria seu indicador, pois estou fazendo 1 top 100 jogadores
e queria numerar cada  com o numero da posição

```php
    public function Skywars()
    {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tskywars INNER JOIN tcommons ON tskywars.id = tcommons.id INNER JOIN permusers ON tcommons.id = permusers.id ORDER BY `solowins` DESC LIMIT 100");
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->rowCount() == 0) { return ""; }
        $fetch = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $return = "";
        foreach ($fetch as $rs)
        {
            $deaths = "".number_format($rs->solodeaths, 0, ',', '.');
            $wins = "".number_format($rs->solowins, 0, ',', '.');
            $kills = "".number_format($rs->solokills, 0, ',', '.');
            $coins = "".number_format($rs->coins, 0, ',', '.');

               $color = "background: ";

    switch($rs->groups){
        case "Diretor": $color."orange;"; break; // se for diretor
        case "Ajudante": $color."yellow;"; break; // se for ajudante
        default : $color."black;";
    }

    // insere a cor

            $return .= "
                         <tr>
                                        <td style=\"padding:10px;\" class=\"position\">1.</td>
                                        <td><img src=\"https://minotar.net/helm/{$rs->name}/24.png\"></td>
                                        <td style=\"padding:10px;\"><span style=\"color:#fff;padding:5px;$color\">{$rs->groups}</span> <span style=\"font-weight:200;\">{$rs->name}</span></td>
                                        <td style=\"padding:10px;\">$wins</td>
                                        <td style=\"padding:10px;\">$kills</td>
                                    </tr>";
        }
        return $return;
    }
```

Comment: Olá! Vc diz numerar a linha `<td style=\"padding:10px;\" class=\"position\">1.</td>`.
Sequencia? tipo primeira linha 1., segunda linha: 1, terceira: 3. Isso?

Comment: isso, a primeira tabela seria 1, a segunda seria 2 e assim por diante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer com que o `foreach` retorne também a chave(no seu caso vai ser o índice) do elemento atual:

```
foreach ($fetch as $key => $rs)
```

Depois disso é só usar:

```
<td style='padding:10px' class='position'>{$key}.</td>
```

Lembre-se que se você tem 100 elementos, ele irá de 0-99, caso queira que ele vá de 1-100 é só somar 1:

```
$posicao = $key + 1;
// ...
<td style='padding:10px' class='position'>{$posicao}.</td>
```

Comment: vlw amigo, deu certo

Answer (score 1):

É só você utilizar o operado de pós-incremento.

> Nota: Os operadores incremento/decremento afetam apenas números e
>   strings. Arrays, objetos e recursos não são afetados. Decrementar NULL
>   não gera efeitos, mas incrementar resulta em 1.

Veja a variável ***$posicao*** adicionada em seu código e o comentário.

```
public function Skywars()
    {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tskywars INNER JOIN tcommons ON tskywars.id = tcommons.id INNER JOIN permusers ON tcommons.id = permusers.id ORDER BY `solowins` DESC LIMIT 100");
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->rowCount() == 0) { return ""; }
        $fetch = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $return = "";

        // fora do foreach - Valor para o primeiro item
        $posicao = 1;

        foreach ($fetch as $rs)
        {
            $deaths = "".number_format($rs->solodeaths, 0, ',', '.');
            $wins = "".number_format($rs->solowins, 0, ',', '.');
            $kills = "".number_format($rs->solokills, 0, ',', '.');
            $coins = "".number_format($rs->coins, 0, ',', '.');

               $color = "background: ";

    switch($rs->groups){
        case "Diretor": $color."orange;"; break; // se for diretor
        case "Ajudante": $color."yellow;"; break; // se for ajudante
        default : $color."black;";
    }

    // insere a cor

    $return .= "
                 <tr>
                    <td style=\"padding:10px;\" class=\"position\"> ". $posicao ."</td>
                    <td><img src=\"https://minotar.net/helm/{$rs->name}/24.png\"></td>
                    <td style=\"padding:10px;\"><span style=\"color:#fff;padding:5px;$color\">{$rs->groups}</span> <span style=\"font-weight:200;\">{$rs->name}</span></td>
                    <td style=\"padding:10px;\">$wins</td>
                    <td style=\"padding:10px;\">$kills</td>
                </tr>";

//Pós-incremento - Retorna $posicao, e então incrementa $posicao em um.
$posicao++;

}
return $return;
}
```